# Yii: How to make an active record behave like a CTypedList with other active records as list elements?

Tags: php, activerecord, data-structures, yii, sortedlist

Let's say I have two AR classes: `Deck` and `Card`. Each deck record is supposed to be a sorted list of card records. When I fetch a deck record, I want to be able to treat it like a CTypedList:

```
$Deck = Deck::model()->findByPk(1); // Retrieve the deck
$Card = $Deck->removeAt(0); // draw the first card (and remove it from the deck)
$Deck->shuffle(); // shuffle the deck
$n = $Deck->count(); // get the number of remaining cards in the deck
$Deck->save();
```

After `$Deck->save()`, the database records should reflect the new state of the deck, i.e. the new order of cards and that one card has been removed.

**EDIT:** My solution is called ListBehavior, an ActiveRecordBehavior that makes ARs behave like CLists. The code is open source and available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/3615203). Feel free to use it and edit it as you like.

Comment: you should answer your own question and accept it as an answer so the question doesn't remain int he unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

```
$Deck = Deck::model()->findByPk(1); // Retrieve the deck

$Card = $Deck->removeAt(0); // draw the first card (and remove it from the deck)

shuffle($Deck); // shuffle the deck

$n = $Deck->count(); // get the number of remaining cards in the deck

$Deck->save();
```